# MySQL v5.6 on Windows 7 - Cannot Connect

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

I have read (a lot) about this issue and attempts to resolve it.  In my readings on this forum, I came across one answer where the author essentially said you cannot connect to MySQL on the command line in version 5.* of MySQL and his solution was get an older version (4.1.22).  So first question, should the following command work on SQL 5.6?
**C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> mysql.exe -u root -p adminpw**
I always get "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)" when I run this command

I am trying to use the command line as a means to resolve the real issue - **[Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]** when I try to connect via nodejs.

Yes MySQL Service is running and it's on port 3307.
Many thanks if anyone responds.

Comment: By default. MySQL runs on port 3306. if you're not telling the client that it should use a different port it won't be able to connect.

Comment: If I change the command to >mysql.exe --user=root --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3307  I get 
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) which I have also spent a ;ot of time researching.  I admit though, I need to specify the port number explicitly.